# Кодировка БД и Сервлета UTF-8 не работает должным образом

Tags: java, mysql, кодировка, servlet, utf-8

Имеется Web-приложение для регистрации документов (т.е. регистрационная карточка документа (описание) + сам документ (закачивается файл на сервер) ). Скачиваются файлы с сервера путем [DownloadServlet v. 2.2](http://www.servletsuite.com/servlets/download.htm). Во всех сервлетах, отвечающих за добавления регистрационной карточки выставлено `request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");`.

При добавлении файла на сервер, имя файла составляется следующим образом:
Префикс (русский алфавит) + имя самого файла.

Ну и соответственно это имя кладется в БД. Однако в БД все русские символы "кракозябры", хотя при создании БД явно указал кодировку utf-8. Но не смотря на это, при чтении из БД, они декодируются обратно в понятные глазу человека русские буквы.
И такие же проблемы с именем файла. Т.е. при попытке скачать файл - все русские буквы - непонятные "кракозябры". Только они уже не декодируются в русский алфавит, и поэтому сервлет не находит данный файл, хотя он лежит на сервере с нормальным именем.

**Вопрос в следующем:**
Каким образом можно сделать так, чтобы в MySQL русские буквы отображались нормально?
В чем может быть проблема с кодировкой имени файла? Я покопался в исходнике DownloadServlet, но ничего сверхъестественного не нашел.

**UPDATE:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPDATE 2:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `SET NAMES utf8mb4` - первой командой соединения. Сделано?

Comment: @Akina, да, сделано

Comment: Тогда остаётся понять, почему Вы решили, что *в БД все русские символы "кракозябры"*? Может, клиентская программа, которой Вы это смотрите - косячит? тем более что *при чтении из БД, они декодируются обратно в понятные глазу человека русские буквы* - а обычно косяк с кодировкой не реверсируется стопроцентно...

Comment: @Akina, В вопросе обновил содержание и оставил там картинку, почему я решил так.  Программа, которой я смотрю, как Вы видите, обычная консоль.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';`, `SHOW CREATE DATABASE niikp_db;` и `SHOW CREATE TABLE niikp_db.users;`?

Comment: @Akina, Обновил вопрос. Вроде везде utf8

Comment: Ну разве что остаётся спросить, есть ли в строке запуска клиента ключик `"--default-character-set=utf8mb4"` или аналогичный...

Comment: @Akina, как только он там появился, MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client отказался запускаться.

Comment: Ключик этот у MySQL.EXE - [есть](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_default-character-set). А вот utf8mb4 - нету, это более позднее изобретение. Укажите правильное значение параметра.

Comment: @Akina, не понял Вас. `"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p""--default-character-set=utf8mb4"`. На данный момент так. С таким ключиком не запускается.

Comment: @Akina, Что интересно, в heidisql показывается все хорошо. Все данные читаются. Теперь просто из спортивного интереса хочется узнать, что же не так с командной строкой.

Comment: *хочется узнать, что же не так с командной строкой* Вот ХЗ... проверяйте вообще все кодировки во всех мыслимых и немыслимых местах. Может, скажем, у Вас там для неюникодных программ какая не та кодировка установлена в системе, али ещё что... вплоть до кривого шрифта. PS. Мне лично вообще ни разу не удалось получить косяк с кодировками "искаропки", если я не устраивал его специально...

Comment: @Akina, ахаха, ну ладно, будем искать. Хотя специально, кажется, я ничего не устраивал.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию cmd.exe использует кодировку cp866. Текущую кодировку можно посмотреть командой chcp. Иногда возникает необходимость использовать в терминале юникод. Для этого необходимо использовать шрифт "Lucida Console" и переключить кодировку командой

```
>chcp <codepage>
```

Где параметр  для UTF-8 равен 65001

[источник](https://anvarichn.livejournal.com/43752.html)